# charlock_holmes and icu4c LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, icu4c

It can happen with macos that your Rails project using the charlock_holmes gem throws an error like this:

```
/Users/iwan/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': dlopen(/Users/iwan/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (LoadError)
  Referenced from: '/Users/iwan/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.bundle'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicudata.71.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/iwan/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.bundle
  from /Users/iwan/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  from /Users/iwan/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes.rb:1:in `<main>'
...
```

Answer (score 7):

This behavior can happen when brew is updated (and this happens when a new formula is installed: by default it does an overall update of all previously installed formulas), and in particular when `icu4c` is updated.

The `charlock_holmes` gem includes a C and C++ part that is compiled when you install the gem. Before compiling, however, a check is performed on the `icu4c` library installed, and its position is written in the `Makefile` document in which the steps to be performed in the compilation are defined.

At this point if `icu4c` has been updated for example from version 71 to 72.1, the compiled C code will no longer be able to access the old version of the library, which is no longer present.
Hence the error.

The solution? Reinstall `charlock_holmes`:

```
gem install charlock_holmes
```